# Comparing substring of a character array with another character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, substring, pi

I have two characters arrays called `arraypi` and `arraye` containing numbers that I read from a file. Each have `1,000,000` characters. I need to start from the first character in `arraye` (In this case, 7) and search for it in `arraypi`. If `7` exists in `arraypi` then I have to search for the next substring of `arraye`(in this case, 71). Then search for `718`, `7182` and so on until the substring does not exist in `arraypi`. Then I have to simply put the length of the biggest substring in a integer variable and print it.

Worth mentioning that `arraypi` contains a newline every 50 characters whereas `arraye` contains a newline every 80 although I don't think that will be problem right?

I tried thinking about a way to accomplish this but so far I haven't thought of something.

Comment: for quick (sub)string matching one should use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

Comment: @petrbel actually [knuth-morris-pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) in this case. As the input string is only one

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev well, I undrestood that more substrings are about to matched, according to "... Then search for 718, 7182 and so on ...", but more approaches are possible - if you expect input to be matched it's better to use AH and validate. On the other hand if you expect short sequences of substrings KMP is much faster.

Comment: @petrbel These seem to be prefixes of the initial input with different lenght. The length of the sequences is not of importance here. The important thing is that you build an automaton only for a single string. I am not saying that using aho-corasick will be wrong. It will simply be overkill

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev yeah, if only prefixes are about to be matched, AH is overkill indeed.

Comment: I don't exactly understand these algorithms. This would be really easy to do if I knew how to concatenate the next element of an array to a string(arraye[0] = 7 and put it a string called string then concatenate arraye[1] = 1 so the string gives me `string == 71`.) I'm not sure if strcat works for this.

Comment: Did you just spend 200 words on saying "Please solve the longest-common-substring problem for me"?!

Comment: Basically my question is: Is it possible to read the contents of an array to a string side by side? If my array is `array = {"12345"}`, then is it possible to copy the contents of the array to a string such as `string[0] == 1` then `string[0] = 12` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not absolutely sure if I got this right. I have something like this on my mind:

- Assume that we have the whole `arraypi` is in a browser
- You use the key combination `ctrl+f` for find
- Start typing the contents of `arraye` letter by letter until you see the red *no match*
- You want the number of characters you were able to type until then

If that's right, then an algorithm like the following should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define iswhitespace(X) ((X) == '\n' || (X) == ' ' || (X) == '\t')

int main( ) {

    char e[1000] = "somet\n\nhing";
    char pi[1000] = "some other t\nhing\t som\neth\n\ning";

    int longestlen = 0;
    int longestx = 0;
    int pix = 0;
    int ex = 0;
    int piwhitespace = 0;       // <-- added
    int ewhitespace = 0;        // <-- these

    while ( pix + ex + piwhitespace < 1000 ) {

        // added the following 4 lines to make it whitespace insensitive
        while ( iswhitespace(e[ex + ewhitespace]) )
            ewhitespace++;
        while ( iswhitespace(pi[pix + ex + piwhitespace]) )
            piwhitespace++;

        if ( e[ex + ewhitespace] != '\0' && pi[pix + ex + piwhitespace] != '\0' && pi[pix + ex + piwhitespace] == e[ex + ewhitespace] ) {
            // the following 4 lines are for obtaining correct longestx value
            if ( ex == 0 ) {
                pix += piwhitespace;
                piwhitespace = 0;
            }
            ex++;
        }
        else {
            if ( ex > longestlen ) {
                longestlen = ex;
                longestx = pix;
            }
            pix += piwhitespace + 1;
            piwhitespace = 0;
            // the two lines above could be replaced with
            // pix++;
            // and it would work just fine, the injection is unnecessary here
            ex = 0;
            ewhitespace = 0;
        }
    }

    printf( "Longest sqn is %d chars long starting at %d", longestlen, longestx + 1 );

    putchar( 10 );
    return 0;
}
```

What's happening there is, the loop searches for a starting point for match first. Until it finds a match, it increments the index for the array being examined. When it finds a starting point, it then starts incrementing the index for the array containing the search term, keeping the other index constant.

Until a next mismatch, which is when a record-check is made, search term index is reset and examinee index starts getting incremented once again.

I hope this helps, somehow, hopefully more than resolving this single-time struggle.

### Edit:

Changed the code to disregard white space characters.

Comment: Basically I have to find `718281` in arraypi. Using your analogy, I would CTRL-F arraypi and start typing numbers from the start of arraye which are `7`, `1`, `8` in this case.

Comment: So, yeah, I think that means I got it right, and the C source code above should do the trick, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I tested it in DevCPP, however it prints `753432` which is not what it should print. I'm currently trying to figure out why.

Comment: I haven't regarded new lines, sorry, that might have caused the problem. Let me fix that...

Comment: Ah those damned newlines. I spent all night yesterday trying to completely remove them from my arrays but with no success.

Comment: @user3601507 It became a total mess, works however. Kind of hard to explain, but let me try: It now has two offset variables for each array. Offset variable for search term gets reset back to zero after each mismatch, just like its index variable was. Offset variable for examinee gets directly injected inside its index variable right when a starting point is found and then reset, additionally right after a mismatch. Come to think of it, that *additionally right after a mismatch* part is redundant, I'll note that in the answer now.

Comment: I was thinking it might be easier to use fgetc() to read the characters from the file and use an `if` condition to bypass newlines. I tried fgetc() but I got a couple of errors with it and went back to fread.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since you apparently weren't really wanting this for arrays, but rather for two files with text inside, here's an appropriate solution to achieve that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define iswhitespace(X) ((X) == '\n' || (X) == ' ' || (X) == '\t')

int main( ) {

    FILE * e;
    FILE * pi;

    if ( ( e = fopen( "e", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "failure at line %d\n", __LINE__ );
        return -1;
    }

    if ( ( pi = fopen( "pi", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "failure at line %d\n", __LINE__ );
        return -1;
    }

    int curre = fgetc( e );
    int currpi = fgetc( pi );
    int currentlength = 0;
    int longestlength = 0;
    int longestindex = 0;
    int whitespaces = 0;
    fpos_t startpoint;

    if ( curre == EOF || currpi == EOF ) {
        printf( "either one of the files are empty\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    while ( 1 ) {

        while ( iswhitespace( currpi ) )
            currpi = fgetc( pi );

        while ( iswhitespace( curre ) )
            curre = fgetc( e );

        if ( curre == currpi && currpi != EOF ) {
            if ( currentlength == 0 && fgetpos( pi, &startpoint ) ) {
                printf( "failure at line %d\n", __LINE__ );
                return -1;
            }
            currentlength++;
            curre = fgetc( e );
        }
        else if ( currentlength != 0 ) {
            if ( currentlength > longestlength ) {
                longestlength = currentlength;
                longestindex = startpoint;
            }
            if ( curre == EOF ) {
                printf( "Complete match!\n" );
                break;
            }
            fsetpos( pi, &startpoint );
            rewind( e );
            curre = fgetc( e );
            currentlength = 0;
        }

        if ( currpi == EOF )
            break;

        currpi = fgetc( pi );
    }

    printf( "Longest sequence is %d characters long starting at %d",
                                                    longestlength, longestindex );

    putchar( 10 );
    return 0;
}
```

It searches for a starting point, stores that starting point to return back to after determining the length of the current match. Determines the length of the current match, disregarding the whitespace on the way. Updates the record length if necessary, completely rewinds the search term file, partially-rewinds the examinee file back to the stored position.

Here's my *e* file:

```
somet

hing
```

And here is my *pi* file:

```
some other  nhing    som
eth

ing
```

And here's the output I get:

```
Complete match!
Longest sequence is 9 characters long starting at 20
```

By the way, `fread` and `fwrite` do not function humanly intuitive, as far as I remember. You can think of it like, computer uses a language that it itself understands while issuing those functions.

Comment: I'm getting failure at line 29 when it tries to enter `if ( ( e = fopen( "e", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "failure at line %d\n", __LINE__ );
        return -1;
    }` I will retry it again when I come back home.

Comment: You should replace that `"e"` with `"yourfilenamefore"`, similarly for `"pi"`. You also should place your files next to the executable generated out of this C code.

Comment: Thank you for this, however I have to do this for arrays which I filled with characters I got from the files. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user3601507 I don't understand it. On my other answer, I already had given a solution for filled arrays; but then you started talking about `fgetc`s and `fread`s, which made me think that you rather need it for files. What exactly do you need, and how is it possible that either one of the solutions are not working for you?

Comment: I read the files `e.txt` and `pi.txt` and put their contents into two arrays called `arraye` and `arraypi` and I used `calloc` for memory allocation and I have to work on those two. BTW your first solution does give me a result but it's `753432` instead of `718281`.

Comment: `753432` as in first `753432` characters inside `arraye` could find a consequent match in `arraypi`? That would be too large of a match, I guess. On the other hand, 6 could be a little too short, however reasonable. Could it be that you are misprinting the first 6 characters? I mean, how on earth can my code give you `753432`, unless it matches that many characters, I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry, I was being too vague. There are `6` matched characters and the string that exists in both arrays is `753432`.

Comment: @user3601507 If my code is giving the output `6`, then it means that longest sequence of match it could find was 6 characters long. The 6 characters would be the first 6 characters of the search term array, which is the *arraye* in our example. I guess that `e` here is the sequence after the decimal point of Euler's Number, the first 6 numbers of which would be `718281`. My code wouldn't tell you this, unless you append it with a `ex = 0; for (int i = 0; i < longestlen; ex++) if (!iswhitespace(e[ex])) { putchar(e[ex]); i++; }` or something. Aside from the `6`, rest should be up to you...

Comment: So what is exactly `753432` and longestx?

Comment: @user3601507 `longestx` is the index at which the searched term has been found in the array being examined. In this case, the `pi[753431]` would be `'7'`, then `pi[753432]` (plus one there) might be `'1'` and so on. I said *might*, because if there is a white space at `753433` that would be disregarded while searching. So that additional functionality was causing all the confusion, I don't know, I thought it would be a useful addition. In short: `longestx` is the first index at which the longest sequence has been found. If there are more than one, it would be the index of the first one.

Comment: This is all assuming that `longestx + 1` was being reported as `753432` by the `printf`

Comment: Ah that clears it up. Thank you I understand perfectly now. So if I want to print the longest common number between the two arrays I have to create a new string and fill it with `string[longestx + i++;] for i<longestlen`. Again, thanks for your trouble.

Comment: I meant `arraypi[longestx + i++;] for i<longestlen`.

Comment: @user3601507 First, you should put a semi-colon after `i++` there. That aside, that approach could fail, since there could possibly be a white-space in between. Rather try the following:

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use the search-term array to do such a job. The following piece of code appended to the other answer would do the trick: `char * string = malloc(longestlen + 1); ex = 0; for (int i = 0; i < longestlen; ex++) if (!iswhitespace(e[ex])) string[i++] = e[ex]; string[longestlen] = '\0';`. You also would need to `#include` the `<stdlib.h>` or `<malloc.h>`, and `free(string);` whenever you're done with it. Of course, you could do the same with `pi` with the assistance of `longestx`, as you wish. Just keep an eye on white-spaces.

Comment: I assume you meant shouldn't. That's just the algorithm I wrote for the comment section. I tried doing it in my program and it successfully prints the desired number. What would happen if a new line is in between though? I assume it would print `7182 8` and the `1` would be lost.

Comment: @user3601507 Exactly, that is what I would expect at least.

Comment: Alright great. Thanks for the help. Finding the longest common number(not starting from the first number of e) of those two arrays will be fun to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strstr()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strstr.htm) function.Consider using it in a loop with return string as one of the argument.